# Trying to connect two tables together by using id value from one table on the other

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i'm pretty new to sql and i'm trying to figure out how to connect two tables together.

I have a table named customers and a table named pets and i want to assign the pets to specific customers. 
I am able to assign them a customer value but only as the id, i can't figure out how to take that id and change it to say, a customer name when i reference it back in a table that displays my data.

so for example in my customer table the
`customer id = 10; customerName = "John Smith";`

then i have the pets table
`petId = 16; petName = Alfredo; customerId = 10;`

Is there a way to reference that customerID = 10 back to the customer table from the pets table so I can pull the name of the customer instead of the id?

this is my code to display the table that list the pets query, `where $row['customer']` I want to show the customer name, not the id.

Thanks

```php
        <?php 
      $sql = "SELECT * from pets ORDER BY petName ASC";

      echo "<table class='tableInfo' cellpadding='8'>";
      echo "<tr><th>Pet Name</th><th>Owner</th><th colspan='2'>Action</th></tr>";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
          echo "<tr>";    
          echo '<td>' . $row['petName'] .'</td>';    
          echo '<td>' . $row['customerId'] .'</td>'; 
          echo '<td><a href="editPets.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';    
          echo '<td><a href="deletePets.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';    
          echo "</tr>";    
    }
        echo "</table>";     
    ?>
```

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * from pets join customer on customer.id = pets.customerId  ORDER BY petName ASC";`

Comment: Thank you, i was having a hard time understanding joins. I learn a whole lot better just by doing rather than by reading generic examples on websites and books. this worked was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes hi there, you can definitely do that with an inner join:

```
select * from pets
join customers on pets.customerId = customers.customerId
order by petName
```

It sounds the query may be returning an error. Perhaps print the error with:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    // Do something with row
}
```

Comment: so i connected the two, but i'm getting an error. Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\appV1\listPets.php on line 29, which is the beginning of the while statement, should i be using something in place of $row['customer'] to display what im looking for?

Comment: i had changed a few values to make my question easier so my syntax was a bit off, i got it working, it was my sort method. Thanks so much, you just made it so much easier for me to push through a lot more of the app i'm working on, i figured it was Joins but every time i looked it up it just seemed more complicated than it was.